# Use .replaceWith() with a condition?

Tags: jquery

I need to use .replaceWith() with a condition?

change this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner second">And</div>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>

$( "div.second" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
```

to something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner second">And</div>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
if($(.inner.second).text == "some text"){
   $( "div.second" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
}
```

Comment: `$(.inner.second).text()` - text is a method

Comment: btw: why the downvote? Not clear? Since I get two right answers I guess it  was clear enough ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

```
$( "div.second:contains('And')" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
```

*Note: this will match all elements containing the string `And` somewhere inside.*

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1zu27hrw/)

Or

```
if($('.inner.second').text() == "And"){
   $( "div.second" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3te1wj50/)

**Reference**

[:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: `:contains` doesn't match for exact string but string containing, not sure it is exactly expected behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, but with the provided information it's hard to say what OP wants to achive

Comment: the option with the :contains fits my need like a charm. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery replaceWith accepts a method, you have better to use it to handle multiple `div.second` elements:

```
$( "div.second" ).replaceWith(function(){
    return $(this).text() === "some text" ? "<h2>New heading</h2>" : null;
});
```

Or you could filter matched set:

```
$( "div.second" ).filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === "some text";
}).replaceWith("<h2>New heading</h2>");
```